# How to append dollar sign before text box and "k" after the text box using CSS

Tags: jquery, css

**[Here is a link to my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jforman07/qaU7K/86/)**

Currently, you can move the slider bar, and the text input will change from 0 to 100.

**Question:** I'd like to append a '$' before the text box and a 'k' after the text box - i.e. 20 shows up as $20k, and 50 shows up as $50k

Preferably, I'd like to use CSS to append the '$' and 'k', so the value is not affected.

**What I have so far (as seen in the jsfiddle link above):**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<input id="min" type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="1" />
<div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**CS:**

```
#container {
width:200px;
margin:40px;}

#min, #max {
width: 50px;
height:40px;
border: none;
text-align: center;
font: normal 24px verdana;}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slider").slider({
    range: false,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    values: [1],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
            $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
        };
        var delay = function () {
            var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');
            var label = handleIndex == 0 ? '#min' : '#max';
            $(label).html(ui.value).position({
                my: 'center top',
                at: 'center bottom',
                of: ui.handle,
                offset: "0, -74"
            });
        };
        setTimeout(delay, 0);
    }
});
$("input.sliderValue").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    var handle = $(this).attr('id') == 'min' ? 0 : 1;
    $(this).position({
        my: 'center top',
        at: 'center bottom',
        of: $('a.ui-slider-handle:eq(' + handle + ')'),
        offset: "0, -54"
    });
});
$('#min').html($('#slider').slider('values', 0)).position({
    my: 'center top',
    at: 'center bottom',
    of: $('#slider a:eq(0)'),
    offset: "0, -54"
});
$('#max').html($('#slider').slider('values', 1)).position({
    my: 'center top',
    at: 'center bottom',
    of: $('#slider a:eq(1)'),
    offset: "0, -54"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/qaU7K/92/

Just add it in the default value at first:

```
<input id="min" type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="$1k" />
```

Then change this line:

```
 $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
```

For this:

```
$("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val("$" + ui.values[i] + "k");
```

And make the `div` a bit bigger changin the `width` of it:

```
#min, #max {
    width: 76px;  /*modified*/
    height:40px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 24px verdana;
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/qaU7K/92/

Comment: Living example is 404'ing